# How can I see how a JPA EntityManager is loaded

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm totally new to the world of JPA, and I am navigating an existing codebase. I have

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "markets")
private EntityManager marketsEntityManager;
```

I believe that spring is injecting the instance of marketEntityManager. How can I see how this is configured?

Basically, I'm tryingto understand how objects in this cache are instantiated from the database. Ie, what tables / views / sprocs / SQL are being called on the database.

Comment: you look in the log of the JPA provider

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an environment that I can easily spin up. Is it possible to tell from the codebase please?